# Does Angular clear property or array on ngOnDestroy to prevent memory leak?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have following code:(Angular 9)

employee.component.ts

```
  name:string;
  arr = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.name = "abc";
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            this.arr.push(i);
          }
    }
```

> Now when I move to another component using angular routing, then
> component named employee will be destroyed.

So Does I need to clear array and name property on ngOnDestroy() method like following to prevent memory leak ?

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.name = "";
    this.arr = [];
  }
```

Or angular will clear array and properties on ngOnDestroy ?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#ondestroy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to as those variables will be garbage collected https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#ondestroy

Comment: What is garbage collected automatically?

Comment: The properties in your example. Follow the link. There you can see what kind of resources will not be freed automatically. (Generally streams and references added to other parts of the application, stuff that is not contained within the component itself.)

Comment: can you give example of references added to other parts of the application?

Comment: @chirag An example (also mentioned in the article) would be if you register a function in a component as a callback in another component. In that case you would have to unregister to clear the reference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to, the garbage collector will take care. Just make sure your component doesn't have subscribed to any observable etc. If the subscription/component still has some reference back to the root, it will not be garbage collected.

To handle the subscription you should use `ngOnDestroy` to unsubscribe all subscriptions. Following is an example:

```
    @Component({...})
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
        subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
        ngOnInit () {
            var observable = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
            var observable2 = Rx.Observable.interval(1000);
            this.subscriptions.push(observable.subscribe(x => console.log(x)));
            this.subscriptions.push(observable2.subscribe(x => console.log(x)));
        }
        ngOnDestroy() {
            this.subscriptions.forEach((subscription) => subscription.unsubscribe())
        }
    }
```

Comment: First of you need to initialize the array or you'll get an undefined error. Second, you can just declare it as `subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription()`. Then use `add` instead of push and in the destroy it is only `this.subscriptions.unsubscribe()`.